# Atomic variables over Volatile

Tags: java, multithreading

Since Atomic variables are volatile, are there any disadvantages of using always using Atomic variable even if you just need the volatility aspect?

Comment: Atomic variables are objects; volatile primitives are not; so a "disadvantage" is increased memory usage. Whether that is relevant strongly depends on the application.

Comment: Your first clause in confusing. If you mean an `Atomic…` var is implicitly marked `volatile`, you would be incorrect. AFAIK, in the line `AtomicInteger x = new AtomicInteger() ;`, the reference var `x` is *not* protected against visibility issues in the Java Memory Model. If you assign a new or different `AtomicInteger` object (`x = y ;`), then you may have some threads that see the original object referenced by x while other threads may see the `y` object referenced by x. In such a case, you should write `volatile AtomicInteger x = new AtomicInteger() ;`. Unnecessary if x is never reassigned.

Comment: What Andy said.  But I would like you to be more specific about what you *mean* by "the volatility aspect".  Do you mean the *happens before* between a write and a subsequent read?  Or something more?

Comment: Note: our comments may seem like pedantry, but it isn't.  Java thread safety analysis is difficult, and to do it properly (from the ground up ... as you have to do if you use `volatile`) you need to be able to construct (in effect) a mathematically rigorous proof that the behavior you desire is guaranteed by the Java specs.  Conversely, if you rely on vague arguments that are based on ill-defined properties, you are liable to end up with code that behaves unpredictably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a concurrency perspective there is no difference between:

```
final AtomicInteger foo1 = new AtomicInteger();
```

And

```
volatile int foo2;
```

A foo1.get/set is the same as reading from or writing to the foo2. Both will provide atomicity, visibility and ordering guarantees. If you look in the code of e.g. AtomicInteger, you will see a volatile int variable.

The primary use-cases for an Atomic is that it is very easy to do read, modify (update), and write operations like incrementing a counter. And that you have access to more relaxed forms of ordering like getRelease and setAcquire. But you can do the same thing using AtomicFieldReference and VarHandles (although the syntax is less pretty).

One drawback of atomic is extra memory usage and indirection.

Comment: Hi Sir, what if the AtomicInteger foo1 not declared final , what if the AtomicInteger have to set from some setter function. A final cannot be a volatile.

Comment: You open up a can of worms because you could introduce a data race. So unless you really know what you are doing, I would make the atomicinteger final.

Comment: Like I said there is clear difference in atomicity and volatile nature.

Comment: Volatile = atomicity + ordering + visibility. Keep in mind that atomic is not only about rmw but also about atomic loads/stores.

Comment: Thanks , this is new thing I have learend.

Answer (score 0):

A Variable cannot be atomic. There is a clear difference between Atomicity and Volatile nature.

Atomicity: If only one thread can execute a set of instruction at a given time, the operation is called Atomic.

Volatile: A volatile nature ensures visibility. If a thread modify some volatile state the other threads get most recent updated state.

Examples :

```
volatile boolean flag; 


public void flipTheFlag(){
  if(flag == true){
      flag = false;
  }else{
      flag = true;
  }
}
```

If multiple threads are working on operation flipTheFlag, the value of flag will be uncertain even though the flag is volatile variable. That's why operation flipTheFlag need to be Atomic. We can make the flipTheFlag  operation atomic just by adding keyword 'synchronized'.

Comment: There are different flavors of atomic. You can have an atomic rmw, but you can also have atomic loads and stores and this is one of the things a volatile and atomic give. From a concurrency perspective there is no difference between an atomic.get/set and a volatile get/set. Both provide visibility, atomicity and ordering guarantees.

Answer (score 0):

1. When after creation of the final *Atomic* object different threads use the object to change the internal state, everything works as if *volatile*.

   However there is an extra object instance around. Costs memory and speed performance. It should in this case be constant/effectively final, and its creation should be done *before* an other thread will have access.
2. An other aspect - which correctness I actually do not remember from the java reference but did read elsewhere -, is that with several fields, when one field is `volatile` on its modification also the other fields will be updated for other threads.
3. Atomic constants (or similar constant arrays of 1 item) still have a mutable state and are sometimes abused to collect aggregated results with a `Stream` operation which can only access constants. This means `Atomic` does not imply a multithreading usage.
4. In `x = x + c;` (`volatile x`) you will read the latest `x`, but after adding `c` an other thread might change `x` and you still will assign a stale sum to x. Here atomicity is required. Or `if (x > 0) x = c;`.

So to answer the question: depending on the brittle context they are *somewhat* interchangeable. I can see why you prefer Atomic, but there are simple cases where `volatile` is considerably more performant, especially in fine grained concurrency.

*A last remark: I am not totally confident, whether I am entirely correct here.*

Comment: About #2: you are referring to the happens before relation. So if a is plain variable and b is volatile and first you write a=1 and then b=1, and a different thread reads b and then a; if it sees b=1, then it should also see a=1. Ordering is the bread and butter of memory models.